# How can I avoid duplicating my own question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

Yeah, I know, it sounds crazy, but I get arm-twisted into duplicating my own question [How to implement Master/Detail classes using Generics and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077441/how-to-implement-master-detail-classes-using-generics-and-inheritance). Now I try to find help here how this can be avoided.

My question got marked as a duplicate of [Casting List - covariance/contravariance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931789/casting-listt-covariance-contravariance-problem). Please notice that this question is completely different from my own. Also the solution I found after few days is completely different from any answer in that question. But now I cannot answer my question, because it is marked as duplicate.

The person who marked my question as duplicate recommended in his comment: *"Editing a question to improve it is well and good, but once other users are responding to your question, you can't go changing the fundamental nature of the question (as you've effectively done here). Posting a new question, in which you include a detailed description of what you've learned so far (e.g. try my suggestion), and what specific issue you still are trying to solve, is a much better approach. I recommend that. Then there's a new, answerable question other users can work on."*

I haven't changed the meaning of my question at all. I just changed 1 line out of 47 clarifying that I am looking for another solution than in the other question. If I have to repost my question, there is nothing I could change.

Someone else had marked earlier my question with "This question already has an answer here". He later commented the other person: *"For what its worth I don't see any problem with refining a question - sometimes its not that easy to know how to ask a question and as understanding develops the question can be refined to be more useful to others. After all that is the whole point of the site. For example a specific question about some code could be refined to give a more generic question to which a useful generic answer can be given. Seriously the above exchange is a bit over the top. Let the guy post a question"*

I truly feel that my answer is worth sharing (see the code below). What should I do ?

The easiest solution would be, if you agree, if you help to reopen it.

However, there is very little activity on that question and nobody helps with the reopening. In this case, the only thing I can do is to post the question again and quickly post my answer. But that would indeed create a real duplicate.

Does anyone recommend not to post my answer at all ?

Or what else can I do ?

I post my solution here to show, that

1. my answer is indeed completely different from the answers of the other questions
2. I definitely cannot post my answer to the other question, which asks how a list can get copied
3. my answer is a great help for someone trying to implement master detail classes using generics

Here is the code:

```
class Master<TMKey, TDKey, TDType> {
  public readonly TMKey MKey;
  public readonly List<TDType> Details;

  public Master(TMKey mKey, List<TDType> details) {
    MKey = mKey;
    Details = details;
  }
}

class Detail<TMKey, TDKey, TDType> {
  public readonly TDKey DKey;
  public readonly Master<TMKey, TDKey, TDType> Master;

  public Detail(TDKey dKey, Master<TMKey, TDKey, TDType> master) {
    DKey = dKey;
    Master = master;
  }
}

class Sub: Detail<int, DateTime, Sub> {
  public readonly DateTime Date;
  public readonly string S;
  public readonly Main Main;

  public Sub(DateTime date, string s, Main main) : base(date, main) {
    Date = date;
    S = s;
    Main = main;
  }
}

class Main: Master<int, DateTime, Sub> {
  public readonly int MainId;
  public readonly string M;
  public List<Sub> Subs { get; private set; }

  public Main(int mKey, string m) : this(mKey, m, new List<Sub>()) {}

  private Main(int mKey, string m, List<Sub> subs) : base(mKey, subs) {
    MainId = mKey;
    M = m;
    Subs = subs;
  }
}
```

Finally, to all those who can't resist to mark questions as duplicates: Please don't do it with this question. I guess others have run into the same problem before and might have posted a question. But the circumstances of this case will be different than the others. Please allow the discussion of the merit of this case.